# Creating SVG outline path of a styled text node in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there any way to create an SVG outline path of a text node, which may be styled, using JavaScript (with or without library)?

Text from which I want to create an SVG outline path:
[image: Styled Text Node]

SVG path I expect to be generated:
[image: SVG Path Outline I want]

Comment: Use `stroke="black" fill="none"` for the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can investigate this source= https://codepen.io/kevinfan23/pen/ZWZMWM

Example HTML Code =

```html
   <svg id="Svg-html-logo" width="481px" height="143px" viewBox="0 0 481 143" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
       <defs>
           <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
               <stop stop-color="#85D8CE" offset="0%"></stop>
               <stop stop-color="#4B8EB3" offset="100%"></stop>
           </linearGradient>
       </defs>
       <g id="Daily-UI-003" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-weight="normal" font-family="Lato-Regular, Lato" letter-spacing="3" font-size="120">
           <g id="Svg.html-Shape" stroke="url(#linearGradient-1)" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFFFFF">
               <text id="Svg.html">
                   <tspan x="3.77" y="118">Svg.html</tspan>
               </text>
           </g>
       </g>
   </svg>
```

This example is not enough for you. Please search about SVG Text in codepen.io

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. I didn't think that it would be this simple. Do you have any reading materials you recommend for someone who's diving into SVG in web tech?

Comment: You are welcome : )  This book will help you to 'SVG Text Layout: Words as Art (Writer:  Amelia Bellamy-Royds).

Amazon Link : https://www.amazon.com/SVG-Text-Layout-Words-Art-ebook/dp/B0170QTV06/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=SVG+Text+Layout%3A+Words+as+Art&qid=1578644769&sr=8-1